# how to Display author and date information according to my requirement?

Tags: datetime

I am created a content type with field **Title**, **Project code**, **Advertise** and **Body**.

I want to display Author name and date information after Project code but by default it showing after title field so please let me know how to display according to my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Steps to change the order**

- Override node.tpl.php in your theme template.
- Rename it to **node--[content_type_machine_name].tpl.php** if you want this for a specific content type.
- Remove

[image]

code and place it after the Project code field is rendered.

- Clear the cache after making the change.

Hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Override the node.tpl.php file in your themes template files sites/all/themes/template say(node--article.tpl.php)**

after overriding template file  comment this line **print $submitted;**

place obove commented line whevever you want to display.

Comment: I have already tried to this but every time its show before project code.
I want to display this after project code.

Comment: what is project code

Comment: by using devel ,fetch the value of project code field dpm($node),place the fetched value in previously created template file into a div and atlast place the  print $submitted into the same div after the fetched value.

Comment: project code is a field